# Grub not loading installing ubuntu in a windows 10 laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I dual booted ubuntu 15 on my hp laptop wich already had windows 10.
then in ubuntu i changed bootorder from bootmgr so that ubuntu should boot first.
But in contrast ubuntu does not load..windows 10 boots directly without grub.
I have to restart using windows advanced startup options to access ubuntu.

This is my first time installing ubuntu.. but can anyone give a solution to this problem??

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`. Also, please give more details about how you successfully boot Ubuntu -- what specific options are you using to get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

I found this page helpfull when I faced the similar problem.You can try reinstalling grub from a live session (USB,CD) following the instructions in the given page.

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
If you can log in to ubuntu using windows advanced options, then try reinstalling grub with simple commands like
*sudo grub-install /dev/sdX    # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda* use -f or --force if necessary

Comment: The exact syntax you specify is for a BIOS-mode install of GRUB, but if Sahan's computer came with Windows 10 pre-installed, it almost certainly boots in EFI mode, meaning that, at best, your command would need to be adjusted; and more likely, a different approach entirely will be needed.